# xcode navigationbar subtitle

Tags: xcode, uinavigationbar, subtitle

I am hoping that you can guide me in my upcoming endeavor :D

I am trying to add a subtitle into my navigation bar. The subtitle needs to change according to the section title. So the main title says for example: Contacts. The subtitle should say for example: Family. Each section has its own ViewController. So a different section could say then: Friends

Now I need to start coding this part but I don't know where to start with and cannot find a satisfying answer.

What is the simplest way to do this?

[image]

Need more clarity, feel free to ask :D